# How can I create beans from properties at runtime with autowiring capability

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I try to create beans at runtime from application.ymal like this

```
config:
 properties:
  service1:
   propertyService1: valueService1
 service2:
  propertyService2: valueService2
```

The class in which the bean was created...

```
@Configuration
public class DynamicBeanConfiguration implements ApplicationContextAware {

private TestProperties testProperties;

public DynamicBeanConfiguration(TestProperties testProperties) {
    this.testProperties = testProperties;
}

@Override
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext = (ConfigurableApplicationContext) applicationContext;
    for (Map.Entry<String, Properties> entry: testProperties.getProperties().entrySet()) {
        String beanName = entry.getKey();
        ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory = configurableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory();
        TestDynamicBean dynamicBean = (TestDynamicBean) beanFactory.createBean(TestDynamicBean.class, AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_BY_NAME, false);
        for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> properties: entry.getValue().entrySet()) {
            dynamicBean.setServiceName(beanName);
            dynamicBean.setValue(properties.getValue().toString());
            beanFactory.autowireBean(dynamicBean);
            beanFactory.registerSingleton(beanName, dynamicBean);
        }
    }
}
```

}

The class in which autoconfiguration was created...

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(TestProperties.class)
public class TestAutoConfiguration {

@Bean
public DynamicBeanConfiguration dynamicBeanConfiguration(TestProperties properties) {
 return new DynamicBeanConfiguration(properties);
}
```

}

And in this way I successfully get the created beans...

```
 TestDynamicBean service2 = applicationContext.getBean("service2", TestDynamicBean.class);
 TestDynamicBean service1 = applicationContext.getBean("service1", TestDynamicBean.class);
```

But I can't understand how can I use these beans via @Autowired with @Qualifier?
If I create beans this way, no beandefinition is created...
if I created beans through BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor, then it is not possible to read the properties in the map...
Of course I can still return the map this way...

```
@Bean
public Map<String, TestDynamicBean> dynamicBeanConfiguration(TestProperties properties) {
 return new DynamicBeanConfiguration(properties);
```

But I would like to call services like this...

```
@Autowired(required = false)
@Qualifier("service1")
private TestDynamicBean service1;
```

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Got almost what I wanted...

```
@Autowired
private DynamicBeanConfiguration dynamicBeanMap;

@Autowired(required = false)
@Qualifier("service1")
private TestDynamicBean service1;

@Autowired(required = false)
@Qualifier("service2")
private TestDynamicBean service2;
```